# How do I rotate button non-stop

Tags: android

```
 while(true){
        if(Togglebutton1.isChecked()) {
            button2.setRotation(button2.getRotation() + 5);
        else{
            button2.setRotation(button2.getRotation() - 5);
        }
    }
```

It does not work.
Turning the button2 at 300ms

Comment: apply rotation animation on buttons instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to animate your views like this. First issue is it blocks the UI thread, and will not update. Second issue is you do not allow android to perform it's own optimizations.

You should rather use the following:

```
Animation anim = new Animation() {
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);
        button2.setRotation(360 * interpolatedTime);
    }
};
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(500);
button2.startAnimation(anim);
```

This does not cater for the `button1` toggling. A listener should be added to that button that stops the animation, and starts a new one in the other direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can create rotation animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="360"/>
</set>
```

And apply it in the following way:

```
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotation);
button.startAnimation(rotation);
```